# Defer pattern for constructors in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, template-meta-programming

In some specific scenarios, I want to run code after the constructor for a class has run (namely: access std::enable_shared_from_this::shared_from_this()).

To solve this without introducing an error prone init method for all classes with this behaviour I have built a generic pattern that allows constructors to "defer" lambdas to run after the constructor has run (example in end of snippet):

```
// If derived from this subclasses may call enable_defer::defer in their
// constructor to run code directly _after_ their constructor has completed
// This is useful when for example the constructor wants to access the weak_ptr
// from std::enable_shared_from_this in the constructor.
// Note naming convention matching std::enable_shared_from_this & underscores to avoid collisions in subclasses
class enable_defer
{
    // Allowed factories
    template <typename T>
    friend std::shared_ptr<T> make_shared_deferrable();

    template <typename T, typename... Args>
    friend std::shared_ptr<T> make_shared_deferrable(Args&&... args);

    // Allowed implementations
    template <typename T>
    friend class __impl__;

private:
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> defered;
    bool constructed = false;

    // Only friend classes may have access to this type
    // this is because we only want friend classes to be able to implement the interface
    class __Tag__ {};

    virtual void __constructed__(__Tag__ = __Tag__()) = 0;

    // Implementation of enable_defer kept private
    // to make sure only friend factories above may
    // construct implementations
    template <typename T>
    class __impl__ : public T
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<enable_defer, T>::value, "Must be enable_defer");

        // Forward base class constructors
        using T::T;

        virtual void __constructed__(__Tag__) override
        {
            constructed = true;
            for (auto fn : defered)
                fn();
        }
    };

protected:

    void defer(std::function<void()> fn)
    {
        // Make sure defer is only called in constructor
        assert(!constructed);
        defered.push_back(fn);
    }
};

// Create std::shared_ptr from enable_defer
template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> make_shared_deferrable()
{
    auto shared(std::shared_ptr<T>(new enable_defer::__impl__<T>()));
    shared->__constructed__();
    return shared;
}

// Create std::shared_ptr from enable_defer
template <typename T, typename... Args>
std::shared_ptr<T> make_shared_deferrable(Args&&... args)
{
    auto shared(std::shared_ptr<T>(new enable_defer::__impl__<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)));
    shared->__constructed__();
    return shared;
}



class Example : public enable_defer, public std::enable_shared_from_this<Example>
{
public:

    Example()
    {
        defer([this]() {
            shared_from_this(); // Works!
        });
    }

    // Factory
    static std::shared_ptr<Example> create()
    {
        return make_shared_deferrable<Example>();
    }
};
```

Questions:

- Are there better ways to accomplish the enforcements of the implementation class and factories?
- General improvements
- Bugs?
- Naming?
- General thoughts on this pattern.

Answer (score 4):

- [Identifiers with leading underscore(s) followed by a capital letter are reserved for the implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/673679) and should not be used in your own code. It's easiest to just avoid leading underscores.
- When using `enable_shared_from_this` it's important to use a static factory function **and** make the other constructors private. This prevents calling the `Example` constructor directly (where calling `shared_from_this` will be undefined behaviour, since we don't have a `shared_ptr`).

---

Do we really need `enable_shared_from_this`? The whole thing could be more easily written as:

```
    class Example
    {
    private:

        Example() { }

    public:

        static std::shared_ptr<Example> Create()
        {
            auto example = std::make_shared<Example>();
            example->do_the_thing();

            return example;
        }
    };
```

It really depends on what `do_the_thing()` is...

If we have to register the class somewhere after creation (or consistently perform some action), perhaps that logic doesn't belong in the `Example` class at all.

```
struct Example {};

struct Registry
{
    template<class T, class... Args>
    std::shared_ptr<T> CreateAndRegister(Args&&... args)
    {
        auto object = std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        Register(object);
        return object;
    }
};

auto registry = Registry();
auto e = registry.CreateAndRegister<Example>();
```

While an object has control over it's own copy / move semantics, it generally shouldn't care who / what owns it.

So the question is: why does `Example` need to "break the 4th wall" and know that it exists inside a `shared_ptr`?

---

Large inheritance hierarchies are out of fashion nowadays (with good reason), but with a general solution, you may need to cope with:

```
struct ExampleA : enable_defer, enable_shared_from_this<ExampleA> {};
struct ExampleB : ExampleA {}; // what if B wants to defer something?
```

and

```
struct ExampleA : enable_defer, enable_shared_from_this<ExampleA> {};
struct ExampleB : enable_defer, enable_shared_from_this<ExampleB> {};
struct ExampleC : ExampleA, ExampleB {}; // uh oh... ?
```

`shared_from_this` [is quite complicated to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082785/use-of-enable-shared-from-this-with-multiple-inheritance) as it is with a class hierarchy.

Comment: I generally agree that std::enable_shared_from_this is bad practice. In my use case, Example needs to register itself as a listener on a child object (that is created in the constructor as well) that takes a shared_ptr/weak_ptr. It's one of the few instances where I think it's appropriate, but I rather implement this general pattern than hard code it into the classes that needs it.

Comment: If it's a child object, and you can change the interface, can it not just take a raw pointer? The lifetimes should be well defined, and the child object probably shouldn't own it's parent. Otherwise, I'd still argue for a plain factory function. It's one function call, vs. one function call *and* multiple inheritance to add an intrusive deferral mechanism.